# How to access array inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array in the following format.

```
var arr = [[a,b],[a,c],[b,c]];
```

My problem is simply printing arr is giving a,b,a,c,b,c

i was expecting, to iterate it and get single combo at a time.

How is it possible to access it in

> a-b
>   a-c
>   b-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++)
    console.log(arr[x].join('-'))
```

The above outputs

```
a-b
a-c
b-c
```

Just for diversity, another possible way:

```
console.log.apply(null, arr.map(function(v) {
    return v.join('-')
}));
```

Comment: Arrays should never be iterated with `for (x in arr)` syntax as that iterates iterable properties, not just array elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var arr = [["a","b"],["a","c"],["b","c"]];

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(arr[i].join("-"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal for loop for this and use the built-in method of [#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the array itself if you want that exact output you have specified.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   console.log(arr[i].join('-'));
}
```

Looping over arrays with the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) construct should never be done as you're not looping over what you think you're looping over.

The `for...in` loops over the enumerable properties of an object. Great post about how and why's [here.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAC&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea&ei=1hSpU52CIqvG7AaN-oCQDw&usg=AFQjCNGZ2O6HZA20l2gys69Wxwj1e6oSSw&bvm=bv.69620078,d.ZGU)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you meant

```
var arr = [["a","b"],["a","c"],["b","c"]];
```

Because otherwise the `toString()` function does not return `a-b a-c b-c` but rather the values of those variables.

Here is another solution where you work on the output string directly:

```
var arr = [["a","b"],["a","c"],["b","c"]];
arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '-').replace(/(\w+-\w+)-/g, "$1 ")
// => "a-b a-c b-c"
```